# How to play sound in Ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, sound, soundcard

I have searched many queries and answers discussing this topic but was unable to fix the problem on my installation. I am on Ubuntu 20.04 and keep getting the following error when trying to perform `aplay` on terminal.

```
ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4732:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4732:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4732:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5220:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2642:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
aplay: main:852: audio open error: No such file or directory
```

I've tried other code, and found that `alsamixer` does not exist and `/proc/asound/` directory is not in my root. I've run `lspci` and got soundcards in return but running `aplay -l` returned no soundcards. Running `lsmod` also gave me no modules.
I've tried reinstalling packages but either it still didn't work or there was no version for 20.04 distribution, so I am stuck. (I've tried reinstalling sound system with `aptitiude` but this also didn't seem to work on 20.04)
Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: I forgot to mention that I am on ubuntu for wsl, not linux.

Comment: Does `paplay` work?   (ie. using default pulseaudio)

Comment: .mp3 files do not work at all(I can't figure out why) and .wav files return a connection error.

Comment: I ended up giving up on Alsa and pulseaudio and switched to a different music player. I am not sure why the soundcards were not detected before but everything seems to work now.